# Get-Job by State and Name?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Powershell v3.

```
Start-Job -Name "TestJob" -ScriptBlock { Write-Host "foo" }
```

The job starts fine.  I then type

```
Get-Job
```

and I see

```
Id   Name      PSJobTypeName   State      HasMoreData   Location      Command
--   ----      -------------   -----      -----------   --------      -------
18   TestJob   BackgroundJob   Completed  True          localhost     Write-Host "foo"
```

Everything is going according to plan so far. But now let's say I have many jobs running in this session, and they have various different names.  So I want to find only the jobs that are named TestJob:

```
Get-Job -Name TestJob
```

This also works exactly as expected, returning only the jobs of that name.  But now let's say I want to find jobs that both have the name TestJob *and* are still running:

```
PS C:\> Get-Job -Name TestJob -State Running
Get-Job : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Job -Name TestJob -State Running
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Job], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetJobCommand
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following

```
Get-Job -State Completed | Where-Object {$_.Name.Contains("TestJob")}
```

Here's a sample run based on your example

```
PS D:\>  Get-Job -State Completed | Where-Object {$_.Name.Contains("Job")}

Id              Name            State      HasMoreData     Location             Command
--              ----            -----      -----------     --------             -------
1               TestJob         Completed  True            localhost             Write-Host "foo"
3               TestJob         Completed  True            localhost             Write-Host "foo"
```

See [`Get-Help Where-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) for more info on this.

Comment: That's the ticket. Simple. Thanks!